# Processing3 PShape.setTexture array index out of bounds error

Tags: 3d, processing

The following code produces an array out of bounds exception (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:-2)

I have no idea why, I have been following a tutorial online. Have read through the references and Processing Javadoc but not much info on the method. Anyone have any ideas?

someImage.jpg is a 1200 X 600 image file

```java
class Ball
{
    float size;

    Ball(float size)
    {
        this.size = size;
    }

    void show(PImage img)
    {
        PShape my_ball;
        my_ball = createShape(SPHERE, size);
        shape(my_ball);
        my_ball.setTexture(img);
    }
}//end class


PImage img;
Ball a = new Ball(25);

void setup()
{
    size(600, 600, P3D);
    img = loadImage("someImage.jpg");
}

void draw()
{
    a.show(img);
}
```

Comment: This code runs fine for me. Can you provide a link to the image file you're using?

Comment: @KevinWorkman https://www.google.ie/search?q=planet+surface&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8x9nP5PnPAhVFDxoKHf0HDugQ_AUICCgB&biw=1280&bih=934#imgrc=DUtjhR4My7C6cM%3A

Comment: Do you mind me asking what OS you are on. I am beginning to think it is a bug with Ubuntu 16.4

Comment: That image file also works fine. I'm on Windows 10, using Processing 3.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to instantiate a shape only once and do so after the call to size() within setup(). The draw loop can then simply display the shape and texture. Note [here](https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html) how the createShape is called during setup() after size().

And below is the refactored code (works fine in P3.2.1 on Win10) you might try on your system:

```
class Ball {
  float size;
  PShape my_ball;

  Ball(float size) {
    this.size = size;
    my_ball = createShape(SPHERE, size);
    my_ball.setStroke(false);
  }

  void show(PImage img) {
    my_ball.setTexture(img);
    shape(my_ball);
  }
}//end class

PImage img;
Ball a;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600, P3D);
  img = loadImage("someImage.jpg");
  a = new Ball(600.0);
}

void draw() {
  translate(300,300,-1200);
  a.show(img);
}
```

Update: Two lines fixed in the code above: the texture is set *before* calling shape() and the .setStroke() method should be called on the my_ball object to mute strokes. Note: If setTexture() is called *after* shape(), I get the same out-of-bounds exception.

Comment: Did you run OP's original code? Did you get the same error? If not, then this code isn't really "fixing" anything. I agree that only calling the `createShape()` function once is a good idea for this small example, but that might not be the case in OP's full sketch, and OP's code should work- and does work fine, on my computer. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: @James Dunn, those changes now don't give a JM error however the image is not loading correctly and the noFill() noStroke() calls are being ignored. I have noStroke() and noFill() at the start of the draw function and just above a.show()

Comment: @kevin-workman, See update. After encountering the same error as OP and not seeing the texture map correctly, I investigated and found the correct protocol. OP, please try the updated code on your configuration.